# OR condition inside AND condition in createQueryBuilder depend on condition

Tags: mongodb, symfony, query-builder

We need all active records using "tag" which matches `search` string in `createQueryBuilder`.

For Ex: Search for "NEW YORK" which internally search for "NEW" or "YORK" in Tags "new, ab, other"

My CODE:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$query->field('status')->equals("active");
if (isset($params["search"]) && !empty($params["search"])) {
    $searchArr = explode(" ", $params["search"]);
    foreach ($searchArr as $searchVal) {
        $query->addOr(
             $query->expr()->addOr($query->expr()->field('tags')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*' . $searchVal . '.*/')))
        );
    }
}
```

It will give result `active OR (tag1 Or tag2)`. Expected result `active AND (tag1 Or tag2)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
foreach ($searchArr as $searchVal) {
    $query->addOr(
```

by this

```
foreach ($searchArr as $searchVal) {
    $query->addAnd(
```